# Não encontro o elemento radiobutton na tela do GLPI de uma tela criada com FormCreator para automatizar a usando a Capybara e SitePrism

Tags: cucumber

Eu estou trabalhando com automação de testes de software usando Capybara com SitePrism e eu não sou capaz de clicar em um RadioButton da ferramenta GLPI. Esta página específica foi gerada com o plugin GLPI FormsCreator. Eu só preciso selecionar um raio específico. Vou postar o trecho de código que não funciona.

```
class CadastroChamado < SitePrism::Page
  include Capybara::DSL

  element :escolhe_versao, :"#formcreator_field_2274_2"

  def cadastro_chamado()
    . . .
    escolhe_versao.click
    . . .
  end

end
```

Este é o HTML da página em que o componente está:

```
<div class="form-group  required line1" id="form-group-formcreator_field_2274">
    <label for="formcreator_field_2274">Informe a versão <span class="red">*</span></label>
    <div class="help-block"></div><div class="form_field">
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="formcreator_field_2274" value="">
        <div class="formcreator_radios">
            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="formcreator_field_2274" id="formcreator_field_2274_1" value="Versão 11"> 
            <label for="formcreator_field_2274_1">Versão 11</label>
            <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="formcreator_field_2274" id="formcreator_field_2274_2" value="Versão 12"> 
            <label for="formcreator_field_2274_2">Versão 12</label>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
                  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                     jQuery("input[name='formcreator_field_2274']").on("change", function() {
                        jQuery("input[name='formcreator_field_2274']").each(function() {
                           if (this.checked == true) {
                              formcreatorChangeValueOf (2274, this.value);
                           }
                        });
                     });
                  });
</script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontrei a forma de clicar no elemento utilizando o SitePrism e Capybara. Tive que buscar pelo texto do radiobutton dentro do label do radio.
Segue o código alterado e funcional:

```
class CadastroChamado < SitePrism::Page
  include Capybara::DSL

  element :escolhe_versao, :css, "label[for='formcreator_field_2274_2']", :text=>"Versão 12"

  def cadastro_chamado()
    . . .
    escolhe_versao.click
    . . .
  end

end
```